# Use Algebric proof to prove the following set A-(A-B) = A ∩ B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm studying for a mathematics class and have been struggling with the following proof

$$A-(A-B) = A ∩ B$$

I know we have to use the following rule $A-B = A ∩ B^c$ which is set $B$'s complement known as the set difference law.

Do I have everything necessary to solve this prove? Is this proof possible because using the complements won't seem to result in the $A ∩ B$ that is required.

Edit-

Thank you guys I gained some confidence and done the proof this is what I got

A-B = A ∩ B^(c) - Set Difference Law

A- (A ∩ B^(c)) = A ∩ B

A- (A ∩ B^(c)) = (A ∩ (A ∩ B^(c)) ^c)  - Set Difference Law

(A ∩ (A ∩ B^(c)) ^c) = A ∩ B  - double Complement Law

(A ∩ (A ∩ B)) = A ∩ B

A ∩ A = A   - Idempotent Laws   (Can I do this?)

A ∩  B = A ∩  B

I think this proof is close to correct. I was confused with the last part but it seems to check out.

Edit 2- Nevermind Looks like my proof was all wrong. Is there any way to redeem my current proof?

Comment: It's certainly possible, though you need additional laws such as De Morgan's law, as well the fact that $(B^c)^c = B$.

Comment: The approach using complements works fine. Please show us your work so we can help you find the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} A - (A - B) &= A - (A \cap B^c) \\
&= A \cap (A \cap B^c)^c \\
&= A \cap (A^c \cup (B^c)^c) \\
&= A \cap (A^c \cup B) \\
&= (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B) \\
&= A \cap B
\end{align}$$

Using $(B^c)^c = B$, De Morgan's law, and distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Notice $A - B = A \cap B^c $. Hence,

$$ A - (A - B) = A \cap ( A \cap B^c )^c = A \cap (A^c \cup (B^c)^c)$$

Where we use DeMorgan's Law in second equality. Obviusly, $(B^c)^c = B$. Thus,

$$ A \cap  (A^c \cup (B^c)^c) = A \cap (A^c \cup B ) = (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B) = \varnothing \cup (A \cap B) = A \cap B $$

Answer (score 2):

Using that property and De Morgan's law:

$$ A-(A-B)=A-(A \cap B^c)  = A \cap (A \cap B^c)^c$$
$$ = A \cap (A^c \cup B) = (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B) = \varnothing \cup (A \cap B) =A \cap B $$